# Rails Paperclip path and url NOT in public ... how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, path, paperclip

So I am using paperclip to save images.
My problem is, that I have to store them out of the public-path.
When I try something like this:

```
:url => "users_pictures/:id/:basename.:extension",
:path => ":rails_root/assets/users_pictures/:id/:basename.:extension"
```

I get an error message, that the image isn't precompiled. If I remove :url and :path, everything works fine. So it is not a matter of my syntax in my view. I was thinking about access, but public has 710 and this assets-folder has 750. Do I have to modify my development/production.rb maybe ?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
:url => "users_pictures/:id/:basename.:extension",
:path => ":rails_root/public/assets/users_pictures/:id/:basename.:extension"
```

Comment: Yeah public/... is working. But it is being ordered, to save those pictures not in the ":rails_root/public folder. And if I try anything else, it is not working because of "isn't precompiled"

Comment: You'll probably want to set your webserver to serve the images directly, rather than relying on Rails to do it.